# LinkedIn Ajax Request to view a profile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post

I am trying to use an ajax 'GET' request to view a profile on LinkedIN without refreshing the page.

I am doing something like this:

```
$.get( "the_url", function( data ) {
   $( ".result" ).html( data );
   alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Even though it shows the alert message, it doesn't appear to have actually viewed the profile. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: what url are you sending the request to?

Comment: Following on from @cor's comment, what format is the data returned in?

Comment: the url you are trying to get information from, needs to be an API or someting like that. Instead, you need to use web scrapping technics

Comment: The url is a link to a person's profile, it doesn't matter which person

Comment: @MarcZaharescu as mentioned above, read about web scraping. You can't do what you are trying client side

Comment: 1) The url is a link to a person's profile, it doesn't matter which person.  2) The returned data looks something like this:                                                       Object {readyState: 1}
abort: (a)
always: ()
complete: ()
done: ()
error: ()
fail: ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ()
getResponseHeader: (a)
overrideMimeType: (a)
pipe: ()
progress: ()
promise: (a)
readyState: 4
responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en" .....etc.}
setRequestHeader: (a,b)
state: ()

Comment: @cor good to know thanks, I will have a read upon it. But just for my general knowledge when you do a ajax post request, does the server make any difference between it and a normal page refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send the request client side due to Cross origin issues (CORS). If you want to extract data from an html, you need to use web scraping technics. Linkedin also offers a public API where probably you can find the information you are looking for and you can access it client side.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api